# trait ComputeMeasuresSignaturesFromGroupByState method compute apply no more than 7 variables

Tags: scala, squeryl

A have a request like this

```
inTransaction {
      from(AppDb.bills, AppDb.legals)((billCount, legal) =>
        where(legal.id in (
          from(AppDb.bills)(bill =>
            where(bill.individualId === individualId and bill.deleted === false)
              select (bill.legalId)).distinct
          ) and billCount.individualId === individualId and billCount.legalId === legal.id)
          groupBy(legal.id, legal.name, legal.address, legal.siteUrl, legal.logoId, legal.phoneNumber, legal.email)
          compute(legal.id, legal.name, legal.address, legal.siteUrl, legal.logoId, legal.phoneNumber, legal.email, count(billCount.id))
      ).toList
    }
```

method compute can't accept 8 fields, only 7 and less.

```
  def compute[T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7]
    (e1: =>TypedExpressionNode[T1], e2: =>TypedExpressionNode[T2], e3: =>TypedExpressionNode[T3], e4: =>TypedExpressionNode[T4],
     e5: =>TypedExpressionNode[T5], e6: =>TypedExpressionNode[T6], e7: =>TypedExpressionNode[T7]): ComputeStateFromGroupByState[G,Product7[T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7]] =
    new GroupWithMeasuresQueryYield[G,Product7[T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7]](
      this.queryElementzz,
      this.groupByClauseClosure,
      this.unevaluatedHavingClause,
      () =>List(e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, e6, e7)
    )
```

how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fork the project and add another method to the `ComputeMeasuresSignaturesFromGroupByState` trait that accepts 8 params:

https://github.com/max-l/Squeryl/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/squeryl/dsl/boilerplate/ComputeMeasuresSignaturesFromGroupByState.scala

Comment: The functionality can be also added using implicit value classes (with no runtime cost if Scala-2.10 is in use).
But a pull request would be better, of course.